# AngularJS page works only after refreshing it

Tags: angularjs, refresh, loading

I have used AngularJS in a section of my site (for 2 pages, using routes). When I navigate to one of these pages from a non-Angular page, I just get an empty container in which nothing loads. If now I try to navigate to the other Angular-based page, I have the same problem - nothing loads. I get no Angular errors in the console, no nothing.

However, if I refresh the page, the content will load and then everything will work!

I have made a screen recording of this issue: http://screencast.com/t/y72wrr8iO

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm... I see it works in Firefox. I was testing with Chrome initially.

Comment: Did this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28377647/144665 If so mark as correct please.

Comment: Ah, I don't remember. That was probably it though :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue also. I found out that it was caused by a chrome extension (AngularJS Batarang), so removing/disabling the extension helped.

Comment: What was the extension?

Comment: Had this same issue with this extension - Took me ages to come across this. I really hope this get marked as the answer one day.

Comment: @Tran Add that extension name to the answer please.

Comment: I don't have Batarang, still I am facing this problem. I can't really find why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If it works after refreshing it means that it is something with loading order in your site. Check if you have correct order of loading, like:
vendor lbirariers -> your libraries -> (...) -> your controller

also check your dependency injection headers in js files, cause you might skipped something

Comment: The JS loading order seems fine, as you suggested. Regarding dependency injection, I'm not sure... I haven't added anything explicit myself...